# Reshape multiple postgres rows to single row with columns names being taken from a field in the row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, crosstab

i've spent a lot of time searching before posting this and just cannot figure out how to do it in postgres without reaching for pandas. I have the following electricity meter data which measures 3 different feeds for each timestamp, and I can't figure out how to reshape it into a wider temp table:

Table setup

```
CREATE TABLE "emeter_hourly" (
    "time" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "device" text,
    "WATTHRA" float8,
    "WATTHRB" float8,
    "WATTHRC" float8
);
```

Sample data

```
INSERT INTO "emeter_hourly" ("hour", "device", "WATTHRA", "WATTHRB", "WATTHRC") VALUES
('2021-06-01 00:00:00', 'spa', 1468.25, 244, 4.75),
('2021-06-01 00:00:00', 'car', 0, 0, 1960),
('2021-06-01 01:00:00', 'car', 0, 0, 444),
('2021-06-01 01:00:00', 'spa', 150, 15.5, 42),
('2021-06-01 02:00:00', 'spa', 556.75, 208.125, 10),
('2021-06-01 02:00:00', 'car', 0, 0, 990),
('2021-06-01 03:00:00', 'spa', 149.75, 230.5, 10.25),
('2021-06-01 03:00:00', 'car', 0, 0, 628),
('2021-06-01 04:00:00', 'spa', 564.5, 224.5, 11.5),
('2021-06-01 04:00:00', 'car', 0, 16.25, 1010);
```

My desired output is to rollup the rows for each timestamp and make a wider table something like below:

```
                     WATTHRA_spa  WATTHRA_car  WATTHRB_spa  WATTHRB_car  WATTHRC_spa  WATTHRC_car
hour
2021-06-01 00:00:00      1468.25            0.0      244.000           0.00        4.750         1960.0
2021-06-01 01:00:00       150.00            0.0       15.500           0.00       42.000          444.0
2021-06-01 02:00:00       556.75            0.0      208.125           0.00       10.000          990.0
2021-06-01 03:00:00       149.75            0.0      230.500           0.00       10.250          628.0
```

I've tried to use postgres `crosstab` for achieving this but can only use if for one of the columns and not all 3 WATTHR columns.

In pandas this is rather simple:

```
df_p = df.reset_index().set_index(['hour', 'device']).unstack(level=1)
df_p.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x, y in df_p.columns]
```

How can this be accomplished in SQL on the database side alone, assuming there might be more than 2 rows per timestamp to transform to columns?